# Inaccurate output while reading a shapefile into networkx

Tags: python

I am doing some work with networkx, which involves the conversion of a point and polyline shapefile into a graph with nodes and links. The [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.read_shp.html) 
about the read_shp() method states that it:

> Generates a networkx DiGraph from shapefiles. Point geometries are
>   translated into nodes, lines into edges. Coordinate tuples are used as
>   keys. Attributes are preserved, line geometries are simplified into
>   start and end coordinates. Accepts a single shapefile or directory of
>   many shapefiles.

My first observation is that the  method does not read all the features in the shapefiles e.g. there are over 31000 points in my nodes shape file but the length of nodelist returns only 4991 as against 31760 nodes. I observed the same behaviour for the lines shapefile. I have a small code snippet below as an illustration.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_shp("Sample_nodes.shp", simplify=False)
print len(G.nodes()) 

#output: 4991 instead of 31760
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Just a thought, does the shapefile have many disconnected polylines? Could you cross check that? Not sure how NetworkX would handle such a case.

Comment: I will do that check and revert back

Comment: @paisanco I have checked there are actually no disconnected polylines.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is then, sorry I don't have a solution.